# Classes in listview displaying full name instead of one of its properties

Tags: android, class, spinner

I am putting class objects in a spinner view and can display them but what's displaying is the full qualified class name of something like: wxyg.dash1.object.abc.adb93931. In my class I have the following properties; gridNickName, gridName, firstName, lastName, password, and loginURI. Is there some property I can set so what is DISPLAYED in the spinner view is one of these properties? The whole class object still needs to be in the list though. Do I have to adjust my adapter or something? The is what I have briefly.

```
        //getting arrays from strings file
    String[] regions;
    Spinner gridSpinner;
    Spinner regionSpinner;

    ArrayList <Grid> al = new ArrayList<Grid>();
       Grid Grid1 = new Grid("meet grid1", "GridHB5", "pqppq", "wdwd","wdwdww", "www.google.com");
       Grid Grid2 = new Grid("meet grid2", "GridHB6", "zzz", "uuu", "secret1","www.ebay.com");
       Grid Grid3 = new Grid("meet grid3", "GridHB7", "xxx", "dskd", "secret3","www.amazon.com");
       Grid Grid4 = new Grid("meet grid4", "GridHB8", "qqq", "dsdsd", "secret4","www.me.com");

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_f1);
    setTitleFromActivityLabel (R.id.title_text);

    //declaring variables

    al.add(Grid1);
    al.add(Grid2);
    al.add(Grid3);
    al.add(Grid4);


    Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    //getting arrays from strings file
    regions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.regions_array);
  //  grids = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.grids_array);

    this.gridSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.gridSpinner);
    this.regionSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.regionSpinner);

    //creating adapters for both spinners

    final ArrayAdapter<Grid> dataAdapter  = new ArrayAdapter<Grid>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, al);
    ArrayAdapter<String> regionAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, regions);

    // drop down layout style with radio button type.

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    regionAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapters to spinners
    gridSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    regionSpinner.setAdapter(regionAdapter);
```

As always I really appreciate you guys looking at this for me. I'm sure this is an easy fix and there is probably a property I am not aware of.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your own toString() method in your Grid class.

```
public String toString() {
    return gridName; // or gridNickName + lastName; Whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sam. Your solution worked like a charm and was just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a Custom Adapter instead of an ArrayAdapter and implement the `getView()` of the custom adapter and set the textView to the appropriate values. The problem you are facing is because ArrayAdapter simply uses the .toString function to the objects provided in the list, which in your case is the `Grid` objects

Comment: My Custom adapter inherits ArrayAdapter... is that a problem?